# how to read excel file and insert those data into database using java and poi or any other libraray?

Tags: java, database, excel, servlets

i am using servlet and trying to read the user uploaded excel file and insert into database.
my excel is in this format:
ID IP1 IP2 USER TKTNO(these are headings in excel & database table as well)

under those heading i have data in excel file which i have to read and insert into database.
please desperately need help....thank you

Comment: There are libraries for reading data from Excel, but if you can get your users to save the excel file as a CSV or tab separated value tex file it is MUCH easier. No library required and there are plenty of examples of parsing CSV data in Java.  Getting the data into a database is really a separate issue and the answer depends on what kind of database you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Docx4J for this purpose... good with Docx and xlsx
http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j

Answer (score 0):

this is how you read an excel file using apache POI library , i guess this is good enough for starters , now you can take the cell values stored in  some collection objects and store the object to Database according to requirement

```
package com.Excel;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadExcelFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try {

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/hussain.a/Desktop/mar_25/Tradestation_Q4 Dashboard_Week 5_1029-1104.xlsx"));
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            rowIterator.next();
            while(rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                //For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while(cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    switch(cell.getCellType()) 
                    {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            System.out.println("boolean===>>>"+cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            System.out.println("numeric===>>>"+cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            System.out.println("String===>>>"+cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            file.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```